# WebClient downloads files to 0KB?

Tags: c#, webclient

The files that I need to overwrite are on my local machine. The files that I am retrieving are from my FTP Server.  The files are all of the same names, but differ in bytes, e.g., they are updated.

I am using files on my local machine as target files - meaning that I use their names to easily find them on the FTP server.

This is the code that I have written:

```
private void getFiles () {

    string startupPath = Application.StartupPath;
    /*
     * This finds the files within the users installation folder
     */
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(startupPath + "\\App_Data", "*.*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        /*
         * This gets the file name
         */
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
        /*
         * This gets the folder and subfolders after the main directory
         */
        string filePath = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("App_Data"));
        downloadFile("user:pass@mysite.tk/updates/App_Data/" + fileName,
        startupPath + "\\" + filePath);
    }
}

private void downloadFile (string urlAddress, string location)
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        System.Uri URL = new System.Uri("ftp://" + urlAddress);
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
    }
}
```

After the code finishes, for some reason, the files in the sub-folders are showing as 0KB. This is strange because I know that the every file on my FTP Server is greater than 0KB.

My question is: Why are the files in the subfolders showing as 0KB?

If this post is in anway unclear please let me know and I will do my best to clarify.

Comment: Not super familiar with `WebClient` but wouldn't it be disposed before the download completes? (since you are using DownloadFileAsync)

Comment: What would be the correct function of WebClient to use to download/overwrite files to my local machine, similarly?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the quesiton in the comments, the following would be one possible way to do this, however it is unclear if `getFiles` is supposed to be a blocking method or not. In my example I assume it is (the method will not exit until all downloads have completed). I'm not sure about the functionality since I am writing this off the top of my head, but its a general idea.

```
private void getFiles () {

    string startupPath = Application.StartupPath;
    /*
     * This finds the files within the users installation folder
     */
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(startupPath + "\\App_Data", "*.*",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        int downloadCount = 0;
        client.DownloadDataCompleted += 
            new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler((o, e) => 
            {
                    downloadCount--;
            });
        foreach (string s in files)
        {
            /*
             * This gets the file name
             */
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
            /*
             * This gets the folder and subfolders after the main directory
             */
            string filePath = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("App_Data"));
            downloadFile(client, "user:pass@mysite.tk/updates/App_Data/" + fileName,
            startupPath + "\\" + filePath);
            downloadCount++;
        }
        while (downloadCount > 0) { }
    }
}

private void downloadFile (WebClient client, string urlAddress, string location)
{
    System.Uri URL = new System.Uri("ftp://" + urlAddress);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
}
```

Comment: My question still remains: The files that I am downloading appear as 0KB.

Comment: Can you verify you have permission to write files to the output directory? Also, you may need to add `Accept-Encoding` headers to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You could use FTPWebRequest for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx